# Issue while runing a python script which has dependency of other files from a terminal?

Tags: linux, python-3.6

I need your help for following issue-

I have a structured python project where there are 3 directories- A,B,C
Inside these directories there are python files-f1.py,f2.py,f3.py

folder A's f1.py file is using a function(myfunc) which is written in folder B's f2.py.

I have imported B's f2.py in f1.py file and when I run it, it works in Pycharm IDE.

Now if I want to run f1.py file from a terminal(linux terminal) then it say- no module named B.myfunc

How can I run f1.py from a terminal/cmd without any issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
# file structure
./A/f1.py
./B/f2.py
./C/f3.py


$ cat A/f1.py B/f2.py C/f3.py
def myfunc():
    print(__name__)
def myfunc():
    print(__name__)
def myfunc():
    print(__name__)


$ python
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr 25 2018, 14:26:36)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import A.f1
>>> import B.f2
>>> import C.f3
>>>
>>> A.f1.myfunc()
A.f1
>>> B.f2.myfunc()
B.f2
>>> C.f3.myfunc()
C.f3
>>>


# or from file:
$ cat test.py
import A.f1
import B.f2
import C.f3

A.f1.myfunc()
B.f2.myfunc()
C.f3.myfunc()

$ python test.py
A.f1
B.f2
C.f3
```